# Entity Framework - casting property on null object doesn't throw an exception?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm reviewing some legacy code and came across a snippet which seems like it will throw unwanted exceptions.  In essence the code (an EntityFramework query) looks like the following:

```
var serviceId = (Guid?) person.Services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "foo").Id;
bool inService = serviceId.HasValue;
```

That is, a `person` has multiple services assigned to them, and we're returning the first service whose `Name` is `foo`.  Then, we get the Id property (a Guid) on that `Service` instance, and cast it to a nullable Guid.  Finally, if that nullable Guid has a value, then the person must be in that service.

(Note: this is not how I would choose to write the above, it's just what I'm working with)

I have a feeling that this code simply throws exceptions when the person does not belong to a service with the name "foo" (or really, any service at all), because the `FirstOrDefault` invocation will return a `null` `Service` instance, and accessing the `Id` property will just throw an NPE.

I asked the original developer about this snippet, and I was told that doing the following:

```
(T?) entity.<non-existent entity>.SomeProperty
```

Will simply return a null object, instead of throwing an NPE.  Also, this type of "safe null handling" occurs with Entity Framework queries.

This seems incredibly counter-intuitive, and doesn't even feel like it should be possible.  I tried researching this, but I haven't found anything along those lines.  Does anyone have any experience with this?  I'm 100% happy to find out that I'm wrong and to learn something new, but it does not feel correct to me.

*As an addendum, I did try running the query above in Linqpad by using the EntityFramework connection, and I did indeed generate an NPE when trying to access the null objects property*

Comment: when you see something like : `FirstOrDefault().SomeProperty` you can easily change to `First().SomeProperty` because throw will happen either way when entity is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` will return `null` for an object. EntityFramework will make sure all properties that are complex types on the entity are not `null`, but it will return `null` result for that query.

Comment: When you say that "but it will return null result for that query", do you mean that this will return null :`person.Services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "foo"` ? Or this: `(Guid?) person.Services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "foo").Id` (including the .Id property accessor, and the cast)?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` will return null for the Service entity, so you are calling the equivalent of `(null).Id`. `FirstOrDefault` returns `default(T)` if the sequence is empty, and for classes `default(T)` is null.

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I would expect to happen :)